# Cache busting Angular views

Tags: angularjs, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I want to serve an Angular application through Cloudfront, when i make a modification to an html file, what is the best way to serve the latest version of this file ?

I use [grunt-filerev](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev) to versions assets but it cannot version html files. Is it possible to do cache busting also on html files ?

I understand that it implies to parse and replace templateUrl for the routeProvider. Is there any way to do this elegantly, or should i just rely on http cache headers ?

Answer (score 1):

I use [gulp-rev-all](https://github.com/smysnk/gulp-rev-all).

You need to follow this guideline:

- Never cache the main index file.
- Cache forever all other static assets.
- Do not refer to assets with variables *`( FOLDER + '/page.html' )`* , always refer to files by full relative path.
- If you have a build process, stage it first to a temporary folder then create a revisioning of the package.